# Node Red MySQL can not connect to docker MySQL server working locally

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, docker, node-red

I have started a container, and he seems that working:

[image: outpuf docker ps]

I can login to the mysql db via

```
docker exec -it mysqlsys bash
```

The credentials work fine there.

So, the next step, I am going to the node-red, and use the "node-red-contrib-mysql". But when, I setup the data to connect to the DB, I can see that "Connection lost", and I can not work at all.

[image: node-red]

Can someone help with it?
Thanks.

P.S. 
[image: inspect]

Answer (score 0):

Host IP address 127.0.0.1 is not correct. You need to use your actual machine IP address.
Or if Docker is running on the same machine then use localhost.

It should work !!! let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I have tried "localhost", "%", "0.0.0.0". But this does not work for me.

Comment: Is your docker running on the separate machine? Try with actual Host Machine IP address.

Comment: no, docker and node-red working at the same machine.

Comment: Try with actual Host Machine IP address?

Comment: I have defined IPAddress "172.17.0.2" from(inspect command), but when I put this address to the node-red, I have received new error: 7/4/2018, 3:44:12 PMnode: db msg : string[22] "Database not connected" 7/4/2018, 3:44:19 PMnode: ff1769eb.e02ee8 msg : error "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.2:3306"

Comment: 172.17.0.2 is actually docker internal IP address. Are you using Windows/MAC? is Docker running on VM machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use container's IP or create a `docker-compose.yml` file to create services. For the first option, to find the IP write on the terminal

```
docker inspect mysqlsys
```

and find the `IPAddress` key.

If you select the second option you can use as host the service name.

Comment: Thanks, For the first: I have defined IPAddress "172.17.0.2", but when I put this address to the node-red, I have received new error: 7/4/2018, 3:44:12 PMnode: db
msg : string[22]
"Database not connected"
7/4/2018, 3:44:19 PMnode: ff1769eb.e02ee8
msg : error
"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.2:3306"

Comment: did you saw the container logs? maybe something is happening in the `entrypoint.sh` file

Comment: The is looks like everything fine. "MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

180704 13:34:47 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180704 13:34:47 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.60-0+deb8u1) starting as process 1 ..."

Comment: hmmm yeah it starts without errors. My next thought is that you forgot to expose the port from your Dockerfile, or if you didn't define the port on docker run

Comment: I did it when I have run docker container with  -p '3306:3306'